# NotFoundHttpException when updating AuthController

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-routing, php-5.6

I got a `NotFoundHttpException` when accessing to `POST:http://localhost:8000/auth/register`. This error appears when I updating AuthController validator and create methods. With default AuthController there is no error but datas not stored in database

**AuthController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

**User model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
    protected $collection = 'users_collection';
    protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function websites(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Website');
    }
}
```

**Route list**
http://pastebin.com/Xq24AQLK

**Htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you post the output of the command `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @HamzaOuaghad http://pastebin.com/Xq24AQLK

Comment: Did you access `/auth/register/` through a form or what?

Comment: @HamzaOuaghad Nope via a rest client, it's an API

Comment: Can you please provide me with your `.htaccess`?

Comment: Can you please provide me with your `.htaccess`?

Comment: @HamzaOuaghad answer updated!

Comment: Everything seems to be normal, weird. Can you post me the error itself with all of its debugging info.. the whole page...

Comment: @HamzaOuaghad Yes it is! The trace : http://pastebin.com/NRBXHnwc

Comment: Okay, when you get this error, the link up above, is it `/auth/register/` or another thing? 
according to the trace, you have never actually went to the `auth/controller`, so chances are your routes.php has a problem.
Or, as in my question, I am suspecting if you actually went and executed `postRegister` succesfully and got redirected to the default redirectpath but you did not specify it in your routes.php so you get this error..

Try this out so we can find out : in your `routes.php` specify a route for `/home` that simly echos a hello.

Comment: @HamzaOuaghad Thanks. I think you right. In fact my user is stored in database (still with exception) if i change required|email|max:255|unique:users to required|email|max:255. The route error is probable because of the redirectTo property. Please, be free to right that in an answer. If you have any idea why 'unique:users' doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I mentioned in my comment out there, and according to your comment mentioning that the user actually gets registered in the database, so to debug the problem, let's take a look at the source code of `postRegister` method:

```
 /**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

As we can see, after the registration, the method redirects to the redirction path returned by `redirectPath`, let's take a look at its source code as well:

```
/**
 * Get the post register / login redirect path.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
        return $this->redirectPath;
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

As we can see, if the `'redirectTo'` attribute is not specified, the method by default redirects to '/home', so you have two possible solutions:

1. specify a route for `/home` and get done with it quickly
2. specify the `'redirectTo'` or `redirectPath` attribute in the `AuthController` as follows:

In the `AuthController.php`

```
    class AuthController extends Controller
    {
        use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
        protected $redirectPath = '/myspecifiedroute';
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: about `unique:users`, I do not dispose of any useful information so far. Maybe I'd advice to check your database driver version.

Answer (score 1):

i have a `$redirectTo` property in my AuthController, overriding the default redirect after successful login:

```
class AuthController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public $redirectTo = '/';
    protected $loginPath = '/account/login';
    ...
```

I'm not really sure if it's $redirectTo or $redirectPath (at least according to the docs, i couldn't find this one in my project)

[Further Reading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating)

Comment: public $redirectTo = ''; In my case it's an API

Answer (score 0):

@hamza-ouaghad answer is the right answer for my problem. But I got another problem : my datas was not store in my database. When using [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) and you need an unique field in your data model (like an email), you have to create a migration like :

```
Schema::create('users_collection', function($collection) {
    $collection->unique('email');
});
```